# Is <short-name> a mandatory subelement of <taglib> in a TLD?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, taglib, custom-tags

I was under the impression that `<short-name>` is a mandatory subelement of `<taglib>` in a TLD:

```
<taglib>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>mandatory?</short-name>
</taglib>
```

Is this correct? I'm getting some mixed answers through web searches (and a few other sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html lists it as optional.  I would tend to consider that as authoritative.  However, the ultimate answer is that it will depend on the implementation in your web app server.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat, but the question stemmed from a practice SCWCD exam, so I'd say that it must be _officially_ optional - thanks.